# Where can I get a tourist visa for Chile and also for French Polynesia in Australia?

Tags: tourist-visas, chile, french-polynesia

Where can I get a tourist visa for Chile and also for French Polynesia in Australia? (This question is from an Australian resident with a non-Australian passport)

Comment: what is that nonAustralian country?

Answer (score 1):

The Embassy of Chile in Australia has an [online Consular Services System](https://tramites.minrel.gov.cl/Solicitudes/visa.aspx) through which you can apply for a visa.

The [Islands of Tahiti](http://tahiti-tourisme.com.au/plan-your-trip/getting-to-tahiti/visas-passports/) extend visa free entry to many nationalities. Check whether yours is among them before applying for a visa through a [French Embassy or Consulate in Australia](https://au.ambafrance.org/-English-).

> Nationals from the following countries are entitled to a three-month stay without a visa:
>
> European Union : Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Ireland Republic of (EIRE), Italy, Latvia, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden.
>
> Other countries : Albania, Andorra, Antigua and Barbuda, Argentina, Australia, Bahamas, Barbados, Bolivia, Bosnia, Brazil, Brunei, Canada, Chile, Costa Rica, Croatia, South Korea , El Salvador, Ecuador, United States, Guatemala, Honduras, Marshall Islands, Solomon Islands, Iceland, Israel, Japan, Kiribati, Macedonia (former Yugoslav Republic of), Malaysia, Northern Mariana Islands, Mauritius, Mexico, Federated States of Micronesia , Monaco, Montenegro, Nicaragua, Norway, New Zealand, Palau, Panama, Paraguay, Saint Kitts and Nevis, San Marino, Holy See, Salvador, Samoa, Serbia, Seychelles, Singapore, Switzerland, Tonga, Tuvalu , Uruguay and Venezuela
>
> Nationals from other countries are submitted to the obtaining of a visa with the embassy of France or the French consulate of their place of residence, including the foreigners holders of a temporary resident's permit (on 1 year in metropolitan France). This visa has to wear the compulsory mention:  “valid for the French Polynesia”.
>
> Foreigners who have a permanent residence permit for continental France do not have to secure a visa. With the exception of citizens of the European Union and foreigners holding a permanent residence permit for continental France with 10-year validity, foreigners arriving in French Polynesia must be able to show proof a return ticket or, upon arrival, pay a repatriation deposit. For more information, visit the website: www.polynesie-francaise.gouv.fr